# fuse: unknown option `defer_permissions'

Tags: permissions, sshfs, fuse

The following error is given when trying to connect to a remote host using `sshfs` on Ubuntu (16.04 LTS):

```
fuse: unknown option `defer_permissions'
```

after using the command:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions username@remotehost.com:/ /mnt/connected/
```

which is provided in [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

Removing the option "defer_permissions" allows the command to successfully execute, and the remote host folder is mounted to the local `/mnt/connected/`; however, the permissions appear incorrect.

If "defer_permissions" is an unknown option, what option should be used to get the correct permissions when mounting a folder with `sshfs`?

Comment: It seems that defer_permissions don't available anymore.

Comment: @RahulKJha It's available on macOS. [See](https://askubuntu.com/a/985369/60632) **bytepan**'s answer

Answer (score 33):

Having looked at the `sshfs` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/sshfs.1.html), I'd say that `defer_permissions` does not exist as an option. However, `default_permissions` is listed.

I've used this and so far it's working for me.

Could there be a typo in the instructions you were following?  (Would it be https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh by any chance?)

I'm sticking with the typo theory unless anyone else knows better.

Comment: Digital Ocean is where I saw this as well.

Comment: I noticed that defer_permissions worked on my Mac, but not on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: when I use `default_permissions` I cannot see inside the mount (compared to when I din't use it). Therefore I think that the `default_permissions` simply brings the same ownership from the remote machine to local

Answer (score 12):

The *defer_permissions* option fixes some issues on translating filesystem permissions when mounting SSH filesystem from Mac OS.

That's the reason why it's useless (and maybe have been removed from command syntax) when mounting from Ubuntu, while it works when launched from a Mac.

Comment: [osxfuse mount options](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options): _"The defer_permissions causes osxfuse to assume that all accesses are allowed--it will forward all operations to the file system, and it is up to somebody else to eventually allow or deny the operations"_